# Laravel Collection Creation and Use

Tags: laravel, collections, eloquent

Hey so im realively new to Laravel and im having trouble getting related data from my database. I currently have a few tables related to an overarching Product Family table. I currently get the Product Family, and im trying to get the product codes of the products within that family. The problem is im only returning a single product and not a collection. I know im not getting the information correctly and im stuck. My controller currently looks like this

```
public function getProductFamily($id)
{
    $productfamily = ProductFamilyModel::where('id', $id)->first();
    $productskus = ProductModel::where('product_family_id', $id)->get();

    foreach ($productskus as $products){
        $products->product_family()->get();
    }

    return view('product_page', compact('productfamily', 'products'));



}
```

I have models setup for both 
Product Family:

```
public function product()
{
    // return $this->hasMany(ProductModel::class, 'product_family_id');
    return $this->hasMany(ProductModel::class, 'product_family_products', 'product_family_id', 'product_guid');

}
```

Product:

```
public function product_family()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(ProductFamilyModel::class, 'product_family_products', 'product_guid', 'product_family_id');
    // return $this->belongsTo(ProductFamilyModel::class);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
public function getProductFamily($id)
{
    $productfamily = ProductFamilyModel::where('id', $id)->first();
    $products = ProductModel::where('product_family_id', $productfamily->id)->get();

    return view('product_page', compact('productfamily', 'products'));
}
```